# Fabric v1.3 chaincode could not instantiate while import 'shim/ext/statebased'

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Since I tried the new feature of Fabric v1.3: `key-level-endorsement` from this [doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/endorsement-policies.html#key-level-endorsement), I have to generate my key-level endorsement policy by KeyEndorsementPolicy.Policy() function.

However, I cannot instantiate the chaincode after I have imported the package `github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/ext/statebased`

Here are the error logs:

```
2018-12-11 09:58:25.518 UTC [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 053 Error building images: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/ext/statebased/statebasedimpl.go:14:2: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/cauthdsl" in any of:
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/cauthdsl (vendor tree)
    /opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/cauthdsl (from $GOROOT)
    /chaincode/input/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/cauthdsl (from $GOPATH)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/cauthdsl
"
```

I know that it means `ccenv` container lack this dependence, so I tried to add my `vendor` directory under gopath to chaincode path directory of my instantiate request. Then I got another try and there are still errors:

```
2018-12-12 02:06:32.976 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 092 [channelforkvepdemo][75cd50e5] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (34907ms)
2018-12-12 02:06:32.976 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 093 [channelforkvepdemo][75cd50e5] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 2 "# github.com/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/sha3
chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/sha3/keccakf_amd64.go:13:6: missing function body
# github.com/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix
chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_linux_amd64_gc.go:13:6: missing function body
chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_linux_gc.go:10:6: missing function body
chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_linux_gc.go:14:6: missing function body
chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_unix_gc.go:12:6: missing function body
chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_unix_gc.go:13:6: missing function body
chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_unix_gc.go:14:6: missing function body
chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_unix_gc.go:15:6: missing function body
"
error starting container
```

I suspect that there are still some c/c++ libraries missing in `ccenv` image.

So, how can I generate a key-level endorsement policy `[]byte` without this `KeyEndorsementPolicy`? or, how can I import this `shim/ext/statebased` package?

Answer (score 0):

That's because of a bug from fabric-sdk-node, here is the [link](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-850).

After upgrade to fabric-client@1.3.0, problem solved:

```
npm install fabric-client@1.3.0
npm install fabric-ca-client@1.3.0
```